# Help with matrices problem

Tags: matrices, determinant

> Let $A,B,C$ be $3×3$ matrices such that$$
> \det(A)=2,\ \det(B)=-\frac{1}{3},\\
> C=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1&-1&4\\
> 0&0&15\\
> 0&0&-3\end{pmatrix}.$$
>   Calculate $\det(AC+BC)$.

Any ideas how can I proceed?

Sorry, I got wrong $\det(AC+AB)$. It was $\det(AC+BC)$ instead.
Thanks you all for the reply!

Comment: You want to find a number? Like the determinant is equal to $5$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has $$\det(AC+BC) =\det([A+B] C) =\det(A+B) \det(C)=\det(A+B) \cdot 0=0$$ since the first two columns of $C$ are clearly dependent so that $\det(C) =0$.